# memory leak when using COM IDispatch::GetTypeInfo() in C#

Tags: c#, com, memory-leaks, interop, managed

I have the following function in a COM dll (C#, .NET framework v2):

```
public void Leak(object jsObject) {
    Type comType;
    IDispatch disp = (IDispatch)jsObject;
    disp.GetTypeInfo(0, 0, out comType); // this line causes the leak
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(disp);
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(jsObject);
    disp = null;
    jsObject = null;
    GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
```

When calling this function repeatedly from a JScript, it leaks lots of memory:

```
var util = new ActiveXObject('MyLeakyCOM.MyLeakyCOM');

for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    util.Leak({});
}
```

I've already tried to release the object with `while(Marshal.ReleaseComObject(disp) > 0) {}` but also no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a C++ guy rather than a C# guy, but it strikes me that you should also be releasing `comType`:

```
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(comType);
```

The `ITypeInfo` object is a proper COM object and it's `AddRef` will have been called by the implementation of `GetTypeInfo`.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work: It complains about the object not being an instance of System.__ComObject or something derived from that.

I've also tried `Marshal.Release(Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(comType));` - while that doesn't cause an exception it doesn't do anything notable.

Comment: Using ITypeInfo instead of Type also didn't help - it causes the same exception.

Comment: Hmmm. Again, I'm not a C# guy so this may be off beam, but can you call `Release` directly? Something like `((IUnknown)comType).Release();` or similar?

Comment: Nope.. but looks like the leak is caused by some assymbly which is auto-generated. Using http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30919888/introspecting-com-object-in-c.aspx it's less leaky. However, i've decided to change my code so it doesn't need to iterate over a JS object - should've done that much earlier then i wouldn't have wasted half a day with debugging the leak..